# 301 Redirect Subdomain to subdirectory on an addon domain

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite, subdomain

**My site setup is something like this**

```
**Main Domain** - domain.com

**Addon domain** - addon.com

**blog sub domain** - blog.addon.com

**blog sub page** - blog.addon.com/post/54546/url-slug-here
```

Now `addon.com` is an add-on domain on a hostgator shared account where the root domain is `domain.com`

I want to make the `blog.addon.com` 301 redirect over to `addon.com/directory/blog`

For which I have tried

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^blog.addon.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^/?$ "http://addon\.com/directory/blog/" [R=301,L]
```

Unfortunately the above code does not work at all.

I also tried,

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^blog\.addon\.com$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.addon.com/directory/blog/$1 [L,R=301]
```

Both the codes above don't work. When I visit blog.addon.com - it simply shows me the default index.html I have up there.

---

**Coming to Part 2 of my question**,

I also need to redirect `blog.addon.com/post/54546/url-slug-here` over to `addon.com/pagename` and I have absolutely no clue how to achieve this.

I have looked up many queries and tried a bunch, but like the earlier I simply get a 404 and nothing beyond that.

I just want that particular URL redirected, not the whole set or wild cards.

---

I am thinking this has something to do with the domain being an addon over the main domain. But the wordpress permalinks code and my other local 301 redirects like `domain.com/somepage` to `domain.com/someotherpage` work perfectly.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Let's go by parts, do you have the baby plan on hostgator or the plans which allow unlimited domains? What is the root folder of addon.com, I mean when you created it as an addon I believe you need to set a sub folder of your root for it which is the path? And what are the root folders for the 2 sub domains you've created as well?

Comment: Hi,  

Here are the answers.  

1. Yes, I have the baby plan and it does allow unlimited domains.

2. addon.com is located at domain.com/addon - addon being the root folder. addon.domain.com being the subdomain created here.

3. the subdomain blog.addon.com has root folder domain.com/blog

Comment: The baby plan does allow unlimited domains [link](http://www.hostgator.com/shared) - it is the hatchling plan that is single domain based.

Comment: So you want blog.addon.com to internally redirect to addon.com/directory/blog or to visually redirect to addon.com/blog? just want to make sure I get what u need.

Comment: The former. I want blog.addon.com to redirect to addon.com/directory/blog

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Given that your `blog.addon.com` is at the folder `domain.com/blog`, place the follow `.htaccess` inside the folder `domain.com/blog`:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews

RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /

# Only redirect if the domain is:
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^blog\.addon\.com$
# Redirect anything to the domain URL 
# http://www.addon.com/directory/blog/anything
RewriteRule ^/?(.*)$ http://www.addon.com/directory/blog/$1 [L,R=301]
```

However if you want to redirect to `addon.com/blog` change the `RewriteRule` to:

```
RewriteRule ^/?(.*)$ http://www.addon.com/blog/$1 [L,R=301]
```

And if you want to simple redirect it to the `www.addon.com` use it like this:

```
RewriteRule ^/?(.*)$ http://www.addon.com/$1 [L,R=301]
```

---

For your second part you can use this rule above the rule of **part 1** on the `.htaccess` as rules are executed in order:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^blog\.addon\.com$
RewriteRule ^post/\d+/([^/]+)$ http://www.addon.com/$1 [L,R=301]
```

The above rule will redirect as a wildcard if u want the exact redirect you can use:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^blog\.addon\.com$
RewriteRule ^post/54546/url-slug-here$ http://www.addon.com/url-slug-here [L,R=301]
```

Comment: I actually figured out the solution simultaneously as you posted this. My solution is extremely similar to yours, except am placing the code in the root of domain.com instead of domain.com/blog - since placing it in the root of addon.com simply wasn't working. Thank you for taking the time to answer this. I appreciate your response.